# Escaping the whole object array with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Can I escape array of object with Jquery ? I got error **SyntaxError: illegal character** when I retrieving **Java.Util.List** object. At my Controller class , I pass object array as like that..

```
Map<String, List<User>> result = new HashMap<String, List<User>>();
// getting datas from database
List<User> datas = new ArrayList<User>();
datas = dao.get...................
result.put("data",datas);
```

When I gettting it from my JSP as

```
<script type="text/javascript">var results = ${result.data};</script>
```

I got syntaxError.So, I googling it and I assume my object array contains illegal characters and I should escape them. (This may my opinion ). So , I tried to escape charaters of this object array but I don't know how to do it ? I tried as like these..

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(${result.data}));
console.log(${result.data}.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'));
console.log(${result.data}.replace(/[\u0021-\u002f\u003a-\u0040\u005b-\u005e\u0060\u007b-\u007e]/g, ""));
console.log($.grep( ${result.data}, function(e){ return e.id == id; }));
console.log(JSON.parse(${result.data}));
```

All produce same error.

Now I am still trouble in it . Any suggestion would be appreciated. My main point to get is I want to use my object array without any error.Please help me.

Comment: To initialise a jQuery object you use  brackets (), not braces {}

Comment: I want to iterate this object array by jquery. By using JSP c:foreach was fine. But I want to use with Jquery. But I got error when getting object array. how to continue...   :(

Comment: Can you post the result.data object... it would really help

Comment: is result a server side variable ?

Comment: @Robert Slaney yes it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `${result.data}` does is basically output `datas.toString()`. It depends on the structure of the `User` object what the output will be.

The best thing to do is using a Java Objects to JSON serializer like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and write a Servlet to output the data as JSON.

### Gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(datas);
```

See [Gson user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

### Jackson

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(datas);
```

See [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation).

### Servlet

In your Servlet you can output the generated JSON with the correct content type:

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

try (OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream())
{
  os.write(json.getBytes());
  os.flush();
}
```

This way you can simply load your data using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: @TJasper de Vries Thanks for your answer, Pls guide me how to use in my jsp or js file argently. Now I havn't enough times for learning detail it. So , pls guide me to figure it by faster way.

Comment: My model or bean object also implements java.io.Serializable.

Comment: when i use console.log(JSON.parse(${result.data}));
I got syntax error.

Comment: Just serialize your list, put it to your result and use `var results = ${result.yourSerializedJsonString};`

Comment: Implementing `java.io.Serializable` is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Now i got it as ...

<c:set var="results" value="${fn:replace(result.data,'', '')}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("${results}");
</script>

Comment: @TJasper de Vries Thanks a lot indeed .. very thanks to you. god bless to u. Now I am so happy.

Comment: Another question is what datas should i replace. Now I used as fn:replace(result.data,'', '').

Comment: Thanks for guiding usage of fn:replace(result.data,'', '')

Comment: I think this may return string value. not object array . Am I right ?

:(

Comment: If you serialize your object to JSON it will be a `String` and no replacements are needed (JSON is native Javascript).

Comment: String is like that [com.blah.blah@121 , com.blah.blah@3234 , com.blah.blah@35rd] . How to convert it into array object.

Comment: That is the `toString()` of your list. You need to serialize it using Gson or Jackson first.

Comment: NO , I want to know "[com.blah.blah@121 , com.blah.blah@3234 , com.blah.blah@35rd]" to array object in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am fine with that..

```
<c:set var="results" value="${result.data}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var results = jQuery.makeArray("${results}"); 
 alert(results.length);
 alert("${results[0].attributeName}");
</script>
```